# Impossible to create an inter-company transaction in Odoo 11

Tags: python, odoo-11

i just bought an odoo addon : Inter Company Transfer and Warehouse Transfer from @emiprotechnologies, and after updating evetyhing in odoo, trying to initiate a transfer i've got an error. @emiprotechnologie support don't answer to my mails about that issue ...

Currently i'm new to Odoo and a newbie in Python coding, and i have no clue about why it's not working !

I need help in order to make everything work !

Here is the error log :

```
Erreur: Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 940, in __get__
value = record.env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 967, in get
value = self._data[key][field][record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 7

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 651, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 693, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 342, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 335, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 937, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 934, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 926, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5196, in onchange
record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5022, in _onchange_eval
method_res = method(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/intercompany_transaction_ept/models/inter_company_transfer.py", line 90, in onchange_destination_warehouse_id
self.price_list_id =     self.destination_company_id.sudo().partner_id.sudo(self.source_company_id.intercompany_user_id.id).property_product_pricelist
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 944, in __get__
self.determine_value(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1055, in determine_value
self.compute_value(recs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1011, in compute_value
self._compute_value(records)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1002, in _compute_value
getattr(records, self.compute)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/product/models/res_partner.py", line 20, in _compute_product_pricelist
res = self.env['product.pricelist']._get_partner_pricelist_multi(self.ids)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/product/models/product_pricelist.py", line 327, in _get_partner_pricelist_multi
result = Property.get_multi('property_product_pricelist', Partner._name, partner_ids)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/res/ir_property.py", line 212, in get_multi
cr.execute(query, params + [sub_refs])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 155, in wrapper
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 232, in execute
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: ERREUR:  l'opérateur n'existe pas : integer = boolean
LIGNE 6 :                     AND (p.company_id=false OR p.company_id ...
                                           ^
ASTUCE : Aucun opérateur ne correspond au nom donné et aux types d'arguments.
Vous devez ajouter des conversions explicites de type.
```

Comment: Could you translate the error message at the bottom to English please?

Comment: @dustinos3 No operator for given name and argument types. You need to add explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

we just get an answer from the developer company !! It was a parameter missing in the config. Normaly every transaction must have "initiator" and "journal". The missing argument was the "initiator". In the company profile a new field was added that i didn't see !

Thanks guys for your answers
Thanks to @emiprotechnologies for their support